# Created custom entity with Entity Construction Kit but cannot filter in Views by taxonomy

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I'm new to D7 but have extensive experience as a site builder in D6.

I created a custom entity type using the Entity Construction Kit(ECK) and then added a bundle with a term reference field using a hierarchical taxonomy and the Simple Hierarchical Select widget.  Everything works fine except when I try to build a view to display the fields and filter by the taxonomy terms selected using the SHS widget.

When you start building the view the preselector screen asks what to show; content, users, my custom entity/bundle, etc.  If I select my custom entity bundle, taxonomy terms don't show up as available for filtering.  If I select content, then my custom entity is not available presumably because content means nodes.

How do I build a view that displays fields from my custom entity and can be filtered using taxonomy?  If I create a custom content type instead of an entity, there's no problem filtering by terms, as expected.  What am I missing?

Tnx,

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

SHS doesn't work with entities, only nodes.  The Hierarchical Select module doesn't support Views exposed filters yet either.

The taxonomy terms didn't show up as filters because I hadn't selected the bundle in the Views preselector screen.  I was trying to generalize the view to filter at any level with SHS but no workee.

This forces me to use nodes where entities are more appropriate, or try some other taxonomy scheme to get some useable exposed filter UI, using entities.

Ugh.